# Large file upload

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iis, file-upload, client-side

There is a need to reliably(*) upload big files (100 Mb+) from an ASP.NET MVC frontend to server. Any suggestions (techniques, JS libs, server components, etc) ?

(*) "Reliably" here means that in case the connection breaks, client and server should be able to pick up the upload from the point where it was interrupted so that no "upload restart" is needed.

Comment: Try .... http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems that tool was specifically designed to enhance multifile upload experience, not to deal with large files.. http://www.uploadify.com/faqs/why-does-uploadify-stop-when-trying-to-upload-large-files/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload. On the features list it have:

> Resumable uploads:  Aborted uploads can be resumed with browsers supporting the Blob API.
>
> Chunked uploads:  Large files can be uploaded in smaller chunks with browsers supporting the Blob API.

So it looks like what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Raised a similar question with Microsoft recently.

They have a story for this in WCF WebApi in codeplex. It's currently at preview 5, but very functional.

Its stuff that will be in the next version of WCF.